# Is fish tickling a reliable survival skill?

Tags: survival, fishing

The practice of [tickling fish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trout_tickling) in an attempt catch and eat them has a long history, and is often mentioned in passing in some circles.

If I was going to focus building a single skill, I wonder if making nets or hooks and line from native material might be a better choice.

In reality is fish tickling a dependable way of feeding yourself in a survival situation?

Comment: How many calories are required to "tickle" a fish compared to making nets, lines and/or hooks?  In a survival situation, whichever method has the largest net gain of calories and nutrients should be the one to us.

Comment: Related https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/20347/how-does-dental-floss-compare-to-fishing-line-in-a-survival-situation

Comment: It does depend a lot on having an appropriate stream environment available. But, we routinely teach a group of kids every year on a backpack that includes a nice meadow with an appropriate stream. Usually about half of the ones that really try (i.e. more than just sticking their hand in the water for a minute or two) get a fish within 15-20 minutes. But it is an ideal meadow for it. Backpacks to other locations do not even bother trying it out.

Answer (score 3):

If you were looking for a single skill in general then i would suggest Wild Food, finding plants that you can safely eat in the wild is definitely the best option i know its not quite as exciting as tickling a fish but it will serve you a lot better in the wild.

**Fish Tickling**

Fish tickling is not great when your outdoors in general in my opinion. You end up spending a lot of time with your hand in the water, which may not be a problem in high summer but doing so in winter for most of the world will be a bad plan if not dangerous, and you need to be 100% about that fish and not doing other things

Learning to make line and hooks on the other hand means you can set up a net/trap/line, and then go about your day improving your shelter or boiling water etc. then come back later and see if you caught a fish